# Jquery on swipeleft event not working on my div element

Tags: jquery, events, swipe

im trying to append an swipeleft event on my div. But it's not working
This is my jsfiddle link:
[https://jsfiddle.net/yumhev1L/](https://jsfiddle.net/o5u68kxb/)

```
$('#testCnt').on('swipeleft', 'div',function(){
    alert('swipe');
});
```

Im realy not understanding why it doesn't work

Comment: `swipeleft` is not javascript's native event

Comment: you need to add the jquerymobile script https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/

Comment: ah, ok very thanks

Answer (score 0):

"swipe" is a jquery-mobile method - https://jsfiddle.net/humanman555/qb8gzdc2/2/

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
```